# Hitting a Breakpoint causes flashmemory to lose writing capability

Tags: debugging, embedded, microcontroller, atmel

I have a phenomenon that I fail to understand.

Im using an Atmel UC3C (AVR32) (together with Atmel Studio 7.0) to capture data from UART and writing it to Flash (I'm aware of the limited write cycles).

I set a breakpoint after the write instruction to check if everything went smoothly. It did, but only one time, when I clicked on "continue" and send UART data again, the data will appear in RAM but won't be written to flash.
I don't get any errors or exceptions (I'm catching uart errors and flash-erase errors). I can reproduce that at will. As soon as a breakpoint is hit (**anywhere** in the application), flash loses the capability to to write data.

The best part is, when I remove the breakpoint, it works flawlessly (I set a breakpoint after multiple writes and looked at all the written flashpages to see if the changes were applied).

I checked for race-conditions but havn't found any. Uart data is buffered in a circular buffer, if the buffer would overflow, then the UART is blocked and the buffer is flushed (there is no sensitive data transmitted).

My question is: Why is a breakpoint interfering with the program flow, to a point, that it breaks the flash-write capability?

edit: A reset is giving the write capability back to the flash.

Comment: Many debuggers have options to stop or not stop interrupts when a breakpoint is triggered. You should check it in case your interrupt continue to run and something fails due to execution stopped by breakpoint. Or, in case your debugger stops all interrupts, something is not completed in the flash write procedure.

Comment: Moreover you should post your code to show us where the breakpoint stops.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of phenomenon could be caused by several things:

- On pretty much any MCU, the flash driver code that is writing to the flash *cannot* be located in the same flash bank as is currently being programmed. When you have this problem, you can usually either provoke it or make it seem to go away by introducing breakpoints, or by single-stepping. Most commonly such code might work when single-stepping, but break when free running.

  The solution is to preferably place the flash driver in a different bank than the one getting programmed. A more questionable alternative is to load the flash driver into RAM and execute it from there. (The RAM method is actually recommended by several MCU vendors, even though executing code from RAM is widely known as dangerous practice for multiple reasons.)
- Your breakpoint could be interrupting the flash programming. Most flash drivers do not tolerate to get interrupted in the middle of execution. You must not allow any form of interrupt to be executed during flash programming. This includes all other interrupts in your program too. Set the global interrupt mask during programming (and make sure there are no non-maskable interrupts).

  Similarly, if your flash driver is based on interrupts, make sure that the debugger isn't blocking interrupts when you set a breakpoint.
- Your flash clock pre-scaler could be incorrectly set, resulting in odd behavior when you alter the real-time behavior, by for example by introducing a breakpoint.

In addition, UART and other serial peripherals may have status registers that are cleared by reading them, followed by a read of a data register. Debuggers that read all registers, for example for the purpose of displaying a memory map, may destroy such status flags. This could also be the case.

Comment: *"executing code from RAM is widely known as dangerous practice for multiple reasons"* Interesting. Do you have links to expand on this? My google skills are failing me.

Comment: _widely known as dangerous practice for multiple reasons_....on some old MCUs (eg. 68K) is the only way to do so...

Comment: @user694733 Historically it was blatantly dangerous because RAM had to be continuously refreshed, plus it was sensitive to EMI and cosmic radiation. That's not as much of a problem nowadays. The main concern is rather that the program might overwrite itself. Depending on MCU it may not be possible to mark RAM sells as data/code, in which case there will be no access violations when buggy code starts to chew up itself. It is also much harder to apply any form of data integrity checks on RAM than on flash, particularly if the code doing the check sits in RAM.

Comment: @LPs And solutions based on the original 68k MPU (not MCU) _were_ pretty damn dangerous, mostly because it required the use of external parallel memories, which is mostly regarded as madness nowadays. That's not a place where I would ever want my code to exist. Motorola/Freescale/NXwhatever is known to repeatedly spit out problematic parts where you have to run flash drivers from RAM, even in modern times. Good MCU designs allow code to be executed from on-chip data flash, or from a different bank, instead of relying on some amateur hack solution with code executing from RAM.